# Properly registering JavaScript and CSS in MVC 2 Editor Templates

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvc-editor-templates

How do I properly register javascript blocks in an ASP.NET MVC 2 (RTM) Editor template?

The specific scenario I'm in is that I want to use [Dynarch JSCal2 DateTimePicker](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/) for my standard datetime picker, but this question is in general to any reusable javascript package. I have my template working properly now but it has my JS and CSS includes in my master page and I would rather only include these things if I actually need them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/JSCal2-1.7/jscal2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/JSCal2-1.7/border-radius.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/JSCal2-1.7/jscal2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/JSCal2-1.7/lang/en.js"></script>
```

So obviously I could just put these lines into my template, but then if I have a screen that has 5 DateTimePickers, then this content would be duplicated 5 times which wouldn't be ideal. Anyways, I still want my View's Template to trigger this code being put into the `<head>` of my page.

While it is completely unrelated to my asking this question, I thought I'd share my template on here (so far) in case it's useful in any way:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" %>

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model) %>
<input type="button" id="<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("cal-trigger") %>" value="..." />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var <%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("cal") %> = Calendar.setup({
        trigger       : "<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty) %>",
        inputField    : "<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty) %>",
        onSelect      : function() { this.hide(); },
        showTime      : 12,
        selectionType : Calendar.SEL_SINGLE,
        dateFormat    : '%o/%e/%Y %l:%M %P'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As of now, I am just adding all possible resources to my master page. I don't want to have to manage the resources all over yet that management STILL be in the wrong place.

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877927

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852928

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually add a script placeholder in my master page that is overridden by views:

Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Styles" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptAvailableToAllPages.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Ns.MyModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexScripts" ContentPlaceHolderID="Scripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="specific.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date1) %>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date2) %>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date3) %>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Notice how the editor template is included for three different properties of the model but the required scripts are included only once.

Comment: Makes sense, but how would my Editor Templates hook into that?

Comment: The editor templates rely on some script module/plugin to be included in the page. In your case I guess that this script contains the `Calendar.setup` function. The main view takes care to include this script. In the example I provided all scripts are included at the end of the page (see master file) but if you prefer you could move them to the `head` section.

Comment: I don't want my views to have to deal with these scripts, though. I want my views to be completely unconcerned with my templates' implementations. My plan is to use this non-ideal javascript "control" until I have a better JQuery or MVC-based "control" to use as my datetimepicker. And when that time comes, I don't want to have to edit any files other than this one editor template. SOC is the goal here - my view shouldn't need to know what js files my template depends upon.

Comment: Unfortunately the WebForms view engine prevents you from overriding sections defined in master from partial views. Other view engines such as NVelocity or Brail allow you to achieve this.

Comment: So there are no equivalents to ScriptManager.Registerxxx functions for MVC Templates?

Answer (score 3):

I Build a simple scritp Manage to handle this, unfortunately i haven't done it for CSS check out [Asp.Net MVC Manager for javascript include and Css files](http://moiimeme.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-manager-for-javascript.html) . Unfortunately, it's not working proeprly for CSS, for javascript i simply just had them at the bottom of my master file, but CSS must be in the head tag, i haven't found a way yet to do that...

But using that I've been able to had script in a custom HtmlHelper, DatePicker which I use with a template DateTime.ascx.

Comment: Thanks for this info! It sounds like you're wanting to do exactly what I want to do. I'll look into this and share any improvements I might have.

Comment: After trying this out, I simply cannot get the CSSManager to work and I don't see how it is possible.

Comment: That's what I said in my response, it's more complicated for CSS... And I didn't do it in my code, it's only working when you add it in the header tag of a view

Comment: I know your implementation of it is not working. I meant I could not figure out how to get it to work. The primary problem I see is caused by the stateless nature of this, and what we're trying to do with the CSS requires state, and deferred execution.

Answer (score 1):

The [telerik web asset manager](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/web-asset-managers.aspx) allows you to accomplish what you want and is open source.