# Too many JavaScript and CSS files on my ASP.NET MVC 2 Master Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, editortemplates, mvc-editor-templates

I'm using an EditorTemplate `DateTime.ascx` in my ASP.NET MVC 2 project.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox(String.Empty, Model.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt")) %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(String.Empty) %>').AnyTime_picker({
            format: "%c/%d/%Y %l:%i %p"
        });
    });
</script>
```

This uses the [Any+Time™](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) JavaScript library for jQuery by Andrew M. Andrews III.

I've added those library files (`anytimec.js` and `anytimec.css`) to the `<head>` section of my master page.

Rather than include these JavaScript and Cascading Style Sheet files on every page of my web site, **how can I instead include the .js and .css files only on pages that need them**--pages that edit a DateTime type value?

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530623

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877927

Answer (score 1):

First idea that comes to mind =>

Template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox(String.Empty, Model.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt")) %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        MakeSureAnyTimeIsIncluded();
        $('#<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(String.Empty) %>').AnyTime_picker({
            format: "%c/%d/%Y %l:%i %p"
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

masterpage or shared external JS file:

```
  function MakeSureAnyTimeIsIncluded(){
    if (!anyTimeIsIncluded)
      //document.write(<script src="correct url") something like that
      anyTimeIsIncluded=true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your master:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts" runat="server" />
```

And in the Views (aspx) that will use the EditorTemplate/plugin:

```
<asp:Content ID="indexScripts" ContentPlaceHolderID="Scripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="anytime.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Each View has to know if its model includes a DateTime type property.