# Limit JavaScript and CSS files on ASP.NET MVC 2 Master Page based on Model and View content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, editortemplates, modelmetadata, mvc-editor-templates

I want to include certain **.js and .css files only on pages that need them**.

For example, my EditorTemplate `DateTime.ascx` needs files `anytimec.js` and `anytimec.css`.

That template is applied whenever I use either the [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834942(v=VS.100).aspx) or [EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430916(v=VS.100).aspx) helper methods in a view for a model with a DateTime type value.

**My technique:**

I've put this condition into the `<head>` section of my master page. It **checks for a DateTime** type property in the [ModelMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx).

```
<% if (this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Any(p => p.ModelType == typeof(DateTime))) { %>
    <link href="../../Content/anytimec.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/anytimec.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

This has **two problems**:

1. Fails if I have nested child models of type DateTime
2. Unnecessarily triggered by views without [EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834942(v=VS.100).aspx) or [EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430916(v=VS.100).aspx) methods (example: [DisplayForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430915(v=VS.100).aspx))

**How can I improve this technique?**

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530623

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852928

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use a partial view and an ASP Content Placeholder.

In the Views/Shared have a partial view `EditorScripts.ascx` which contains the tags defining the scripts to be included in your editing pages.

Then put a placeholder in the Site.Master `<head>` tag, something like this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
```

The, in any view that you want/need the scripts, put this code:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("EditorScripts");  %>
</asp:Content>
```

This isn't a perfect solution and isn't as dynamic as you would like. The reason for using a partial view is that if you decide to update or add more scripts to those views, then you only have to update it in one location.

Another way would be to have a `Editor.Master` page that contains these scripts and other editor specific things then have that master use the `Site.Master` as it's master page. Then all editor views would have the `Editor.Master` as their master page.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I think the [telerik web asset manager](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/web-asset-managers.aspx) allows you to accomplish what you want and is open source.